# Add to classpath external libraries in intellij 2017.3 on run application without changing scope

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, classpath

Hi guys I have a problem in IntelliJ IDEA. I have a configuration for run my application. When I run it somes libraries added like dependencies in my module and defined with scope "Provided" are not added to classpath and give me a class not found exception.
If I change the scope from "Provided" to "Compile" it does work.

But i'm not sure it is right becouse in my pom.xml they are configured with scope "Provided" and when I run maven configuration the dependencies are changed to "Provided" in project structure and it does not work again.

My question:

**Is there a way to include some dependecies in classpath during run without changing the scope in pom.xml?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1 has an option to include the dependencies with the provided scope into classpath, it's available for some run/debug configurations, like [Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kc3dk.png) and [Spring Boot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qj5Rm.png).